# How to add JS functionality to side menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I started to add some JS but the script isn't working and I'm not sure what I can do from here to make it work. So the code is supposed to listen for the click event and in turn either open or close the menu depending on its position. The id is used so that if the hamburger menu is clicked the menu will slide out 100%. The X is then on the menu to close the menu, however, when I press the hamburger icon the menu isn't sliding in, and when it's tested with the menu out the X isn't closing it.

```js
const menuTrigger = document.getElementById('trigger'); //1
menuTrigger.addEventListener("click", open); //5

const closeMenu = document.getElementById("closer"); //2
closeMenu.addEventListener("click", closed); //3

const sideMenu = document.getElementById('side-menu'); //4

function open() {
  sideMenu.classList.add("show");
}

function closed() {
  sideMenu.classList.remove("show");
}
```

```css
.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0%);
  background-color: white;
}

#side-menu {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: #edeae5;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 20%;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-right">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#nav"> Home </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=# services> Services </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#team"> Meet The Team</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#philosophy"> Philosophy</a> </li>
    <li id="trigger"> <svg class="hamburger" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" style=" fill:#FFFFFF;"><path d="M 2 5 L 2 7 L 22 7 L 22 5 L 2                                        5 z M 2 11 L 2 13 L 22 13 L 22 11 L 2 11 z M 2 17 L 2 19 L 22 19 L 22 17 L 2 17 z"></path></svg>      </li>
  </ul>
</div>

  <aside id="side-menu">
        <div class="side-head">
            <h1 id="side-img">
                CLIK
            </h1>
            <div class="side-right">
                <h1 id="closer">
                    X
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="side-menu-links">
            <ul>
                <li class="side-menu-indv-link"> <img class="side-link-img" src="serv-black.png" alt=""> <a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                <li class=" side-menu-indv-link"> <img class="side-link-img" src="team-balck.png" alt=""><a href="#team">Meet The Team</a></li>
                <li class=" side-menu-indv-link"> <img class="side-link-img" src="phil-black.png" alt=""><a href="#philosophy">Philosophy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="side-menu-contact">
            <div class="side-menu-links">
                <ul>
                    <li class="side-menu-indv-link"> <img class="side-link-img" src="fb2.png" alt=""> <a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li class="side-menu-indv-link"> <img class="side-link-img" src="instagram2.png" alt=""> <a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
                    <li class="side-menu-indv-link"> <img class="side-link-img" src="whatsapp.png" alt=""> <a href="#">Whatspp</a></li>
                </ul>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>
```

Comment: can you give output view image you want, your question is litte bit of confusing

Comment: There are several problems in your example. The first is that your HTML doesn't include an element with `id="closer"`, so attempting `closeMenu.addEventListener(...)` throws an error, halting your script's execution. Open the dev tools in the browser and look at the errors. They'll tell you a lot about what the problems are. Fix the first error and run it again.

Comment: it does have a closer it is in the aside element that isn't here

Comment: Can you share more codes including `#side-menu` and `#closer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary problem is that id selectors in CSS have [higher specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#selector_weight_categories) than class selectors, so `.show` on its own can't override the `transform` (or anything else) that's declared in `#side-menu`.

Adding the id to the selector in the CSS, making it `#side-menu.show` instead of just `.show` gives it higher specificity so its rules can override the ones in `#side-menu`.

```css
/* do this */
#side-menu.show {
}

/* instead of this */
.show {
}
```

```js
const menuTrigger = document.getElementById('trigger'); //1
menuTrigger.addEventListener("click", open); //5

const closeMenu = document.getElementById("closer"); //2
closeMenu?.addEventListener("click", closed); //3

const sideMenu = document.getElementById('side-menu'); //4

function open() {
  sideMenu.classList.toggle("show");
}

function closed() {
  sideMenu.classList.remove("show");
}
```

```css
#side-menu.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0%);
  background-color: white;
}

#side-menu {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: #edeae5;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 20%;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-right">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#nav"> Home </a> </li>
    <li> <a href=# services> Services </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#team"> Meet The Team</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#philosophy"> Philosophy</a> </li>
    <li id="trigger"> <svg class="hamburger" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="fill:red;"><path d="M 2 5 L 2 7 L 22 7 L 22 5 L 2                                        5 z M 2 11 L 2 13 L 22 13 L 22 11 L 2 11 z M 2 17 L 2 19 L 22 19 L 22 17 L 2 17 z"></path></svg>      </li>
  </ul>
</div>

  <aside id="side-menu">
        <div class="side-head">
            <h1 id="side-img">
                CLIK
            </h1>
            <div class="side-right">
                <h1 id="closer">
                    X
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="side-menu-links">
            <ul>
                <li class="side-menu-indv-link"> <img class="side-link-img" src="serv-black.png" alt=""> <a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                <li class=" side-menu-indv-link"> <img class="side-link-img" src="team-balck.png" alt=""><a href="#team">Meet The Team</a></li>
                <li class=" side-menu-indv-link"> <img class="side-link-img" src="phil-black.png" alt=""><a href="#philosophy">Philosophy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="side-menu-contact">
            <div class="side-menu-links">
                <ul>
                    <li class="side-menu-indv-link"> <img class="side-link-img" src="fb2.png" alt=""> <a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li class="side-menu-indv-link"> <img class="side-link-img" src="instagram2.png" alt=""> <a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
                    <li class="side-menu-indv-link"> <img class="side-link-img" src="whatsapp.png" alt=""> <a href="#">Whatspp</a></li>
                </ul>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>
```